# Find Core Data Entities through two 1-to-1 relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Boundary <--> Datasets <-->> DataA

I want to find all Entities of `DataA` that belong to `Boundary` boundary1;

I tried:

```
NSPredicate *predication = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormant:@"datasets.boundary.boundaryID == %@", myBoundaryID];
```

but it has issue when trying to find the `Boundary`'s properties.

My other thought was:

```
NSArray *savedAnalysis = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[dataset.savedAnalysis allObjects]];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:NAME ascending:TRUE];
NSArray *descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];

self.datasourceSavedAnalysis = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[savedAnalysis sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors]];
```

But I don't know how to sort the Core Data Entities in the array.

I am not a database guy and I'm having trouble figuring out the logic to this stuff.

Comment: Your first predicate looks OK to me, what "issues" do you have?

Comment: Ugh. A comedy of errors: I imported the wrong file (Boundarier.h vs Boundary.h) and at some point of testing, I adding a line fetching all dataset sorted by name property. I had deleted the name property. My predicate does work as intended.

Comment: So there is no question?

Comment: nope. Can i delete it even though there is an answer?

Comment: You cannot delete your question if it has upvoted answers, compare http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103904/why-i-cant-delete-my-own-question-which-has-answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
NSPredicate *predication = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormant:@"datasets.boundary == %@", myBoundary];
```

wWhere `myBoundary` is a Boundary entity.